# Provide snippets based on VSCode settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I’ve developed a VSCode extension which supports Axibase Charts syntax, a domain-specific language. Typically a configuration will look something like this.

```
 [series]
   entity = entity-1
   metric = metric-1
```

The extension contains several snippets which streamline the configuration process by eliminating the need for re-typing repetitive words.
Some users write configurations using databases other than ATSD (Axibase database) where entity and metric settings are replaced by table and attribute for example:

```
 [series]
   table = table-1
   attribute = attribute-1
```

How can I provide two unique sets of snippets: One with metric and entity and another with table and attribute, based on the extension configuration?